# Cannot import QtGui from PyQt4

Tags: import, pyqt4, python-3.6, qtgui

I have seen this probleme already in many post but none of the answers helped me.
So, here is my probleme.

I am on windows.
I have python 3.6 version

1) I dowload a wheel file (PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl) of PyQt4 there:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

And I saved it here: C:\Users\Anne-Sophie

2) I open a shell window as admin and I run "pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"

The installation seems to work even if I get the message:

```
Requirement 'PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
```

When I re-run "pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl" I still get this message but I also get `"Requirement already satisfied: PyQt4==4.11.4 from file:///C:/WINDOWS/system32/PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl in c:\users\anne-sophie\anaconda3\lib\site-packages"`

3) Now, when I open a python notebook and write "`import PyQt4`" I don't get any error.

But when I write `from PyQt4 import QtGui` I get the error message: `ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui'`

4) I went to `C:\Users\Anne-Sophie\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4` and I saw that QtGui was not in PyQt4 but in PyQt4/sip so I write `from PyQt4.sip import QtGui` this is working....

5) I go to this website for beginers with PyQt4:
https://pythonprogramming.net/basic-gui-pyqt-tutorial/

And I write:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.sip import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

I get the error: `AttributeError: module 'PyQt4.sip.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'`

> Finally here are my questions:
>
> Q1: do you think that `Requirement
>   'PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the
>   file does not exist` is a problem (step 2) if import PyQt4 is
>   working?
>
> Q2: do you know what I am doing wrong? nobody is using `from PyQt4.sip
>   import QtGui` so I am not sure that I should do it..... Moreover,
>   even when I do it, I still get error when I go further
>
> Q3: does someone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** I think that you get the error message (`'PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist`) because you run the `pip` command from a different directory than where you saved the wheel file, so pip couldn't find the wheel file. It probably went ahead and downloaded it from the Python Package index because the second time you ran Pip it said that PyQt4 was already installed.

**Q2:** No, you should not have `sip` in your import statements. Just `from PyQt4 import QtGui` should work. There is something wrong with your installation.

**Q3:** The problem is most likely that you have installed `PyQt4` using `pip` next to the `pyqt` package of Anaconda (you can check this with the `conda list` command). You cannot do this for PyQt. Pip and Anaconda typically do work together well but in case of PyQt they don't because the package names differ.

I recommend that you reinstall Anaconda and then use only Anaconda to install PyQt.

Perhaps you already tried this but went with pip because PyQt4 isn't available for Python 3.6. If you only want to try the tutorial you could downgrade to Python 3.5. Another option is to use PyQt5. The biggest difference with PyQt4 is that the the `QtGui` package has been split into `QtWidgets` and `QtGui`. So translating the examples to PyQt5 should be easy.